# 2 network tunnels from 2 providers to 1 machine running docker, will this expose all containers on both tunnels?

Tags: docker, tunneling, cloudflare

I have a server running multiple docker containers, accessible through tunneling.

I want to create a new tunnel that is separate from the one I already have. Will the new tunnel service interfere or expose the other containers running under the other tunnel?

For example, I have a Cloudflare tunnel to allow access via Warp to my websites.
I want to create a game server that uses the playit.gg tunnel, but I don't want the other services affected or connected to that tunnel.

What are the risks, and is it even possible to have 2 tunnels the way I'm talking about doing it? And will it be a problem for the Cloudflare tunnel if I install the second tunnel with playit.gg?

Comment: It will depend on how the tunnels are created ...